# How do I modify all of a selected id's child li and div's element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

- I want to access id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-1" to id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-31" id's inside a class and apply the animation play state property.

here is my code:

```
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-anim"><ol>

<li id="p5pg5QXlX-an-scene-0" >
<div class="p5pg5QXlX-an-stage">
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-1"><div><img  height="416" width="320"     src="assets/overlay1.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-2"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/stars-and-chand.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-3"><div><img  height="75" width="320"  src="assets/stars-support.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-4"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/page1-bottom-design.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-5"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/page1-minars.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-6"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/ramadan.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-7"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/mubarak.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-8"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/page1hw.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-9"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/panel.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-10"></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-11"></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-12"><div><img  height="89" width="89"  src="assets/rplay.png"></div></div>
</div>
</li>

<li id="p5pg5QXlX-an-scene-7" >
<div class="p5pg5QXlX-an-stage">
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-13"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/overlay2.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-14"><span>Receiver Name</span></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-15"><span>Wishing you a wonderful Birthday and a prosperous year ahead!</span></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-16"><div><img  height="119" width="111"  src="assets/page2-logo.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-17"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/page2hw.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-18"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/panel.png"></div></div>
</div>
</li>

<li id="p5pg5QXlX-an-scene-4" >
<div class="p5pg5QXlX-an-stage">
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-19"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/overlay3.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-20"><div><img  height="350" width="639"  src="assets/3-3.jpg"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-21"><div><img  height="350" width="639"  src="assets/3-1.jpg"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-22"><div><img  height="350" width="639"  src="assets/3-2.jpg"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-23"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/page2hw.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-24"><div><img  height="416" width="320"  src="assets/panel.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-25"><div><img  height="40" width="320"  src="assets/strip.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-26"><div><img  height="40" width="54"  src="assets/map.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-27"><div><img  height="40" width="54"  src="assets/phone.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-28"><div><img  height="40" width="54"  src="assets/url.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-29"><div><img  height="40" width="54"  src="assets/email.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-30"><div><img  height="39" width="43"  src="assets/giftcard.png"></div></div>
<div id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-31"><div><img  height="40" width="50"  src="assets/social.png"></div></div>
</div>
</li>

</ol>
</div>
```

**i want to apply animation state property to all the id's from id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-1" to id="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-31" so please tell me how to access the id's inside a class?**

i have done this:

```
var id = document.querySelectorAll("#p5pg5QXlX-an-anim > ol> li > div > div");
        [].forEach.call(id, function(el, i) {
            el.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
            el.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
        });
```

but it runs only for the first li element with not for all li element so please help me out &

**because i want a generic code of this so please help me in this & try to give sol'n in javascript**

Comment: OK, so you'd like to target all the `div`s with ID-* which are also all the `div`s that are children of `div`s that are children of `li`s? Here is your example, and it works as is: http://jsfiddle.net/hp236gfh/2/ (I took out the images and added `test` to make it easier to see) - if this isn't correct can you explain differently what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly be more specific with your selector by using:

```
tag[attribute^="value"]
```

This will selector any tag beginning with the value you specify.
In your case I believe you would want to try:

```
li[id^="p5pg5QXlX-an-obj-"]
```

All of your id's start with that string. I hope this helps.

Comment: so how i write in id variable?